# How to get each value from Match with or without foreach loop

Tags: loops, foreach, match

I am trying to insert 4 values coming from a match() method, into 4 different textboxes, one by one, but couldn't manage to escape from the loop after the first value put in to the first textbox, this makes that 4 value to appear in the first textbox one by one, then jumping to the next textbox to do the same. Here's my code:

```
       for (int g = 0; g <5; g++)  //tried this inside foreach() ; no result
                         {
                                 foreach (Match m in mc)
                                 {
                                     /////each foreach returns 4 value, which then should be feed to textbox13 to 16, one by one.
                                     if (g == 1) { textBox13.Text = m.Groups[0].Value; MessageBox.Show(m.Groups[0].Value); continue; }
                                     //but continue;'s are not breaking the loop
                                         if (g == 2) { textBox14.Text = m.Groups[0].Value; MessageBox.Show(m.Groups[0].Value); continue; }
                                       //all four value appears in the first textbox(textBox13), one by one, then jumps to 2nd textbox(textBox14) and does the same w/ the same values
                                     ////until the 4th textbox (textbox16)...

                                             if (g == 3) { textBox15.Text = m.Groups[0].Value; MessageBox.Show(m.Groups[0].Value); continue; }

                                                 if (g == 4)
                                                 {
                                                     textBox16.Text = m.Groups[0].Value; MessageBox.Show(m.Groups[0].Value);
                                                     sendrow();
                                                     textBox13.Text = "";
                                                     textBox14.Text = "";
                                                     textBox15.Text = "";
                                                     textBox16.Text = "";
                                                     g = 0;          // then all textboxes emptied for the next group of 4 values...
                                                     continue;       //coming from a higher-loop, before the 1st for(), which is NOT shown here.
                                     }
                         }
                     }
```

Where am I making mistake with the foreach() loop?Is there a feature of this Match that  we can pick any of the values by their index, just like we do it with its .Groups[index].Value ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the job. Sorry to bother.(Delete if irrelevant to others please)

```
                     ICollection<string> mc = Regex.Matches(ztring, @"\d+(\.\d{1,4})?").Cast<Match>()
                     .Select(x => x.Groups[0].Value)
                     .ToList();

                     foreach (string m in mc)
                     { MessageBox.Show(m);
                         textBox13.Text += Environment.NewLine + m; }

                                 for (int f = 0; f < textBox13.Lines.Length+1; f++)
                                 {
                                     string opn_val= textBox10.Lines[0];
                                     string high_val = textBox10.Lines[1];
                                     string low_val = textBox10.Lines[2];
                                     string close_val = textBox10.Lines[3];

                                     if (f == 1) { MessageBox.Show(textBox10.Lines[0]); }
                                     if (f == 2) { MessageBox.Show(textBox10.Lines[1]); }
                                     if (f == 3) { MessageBox.Show(textBox10.Lines[2]); }
                                     if (f == 4) { MessageBox.Show(textBox10.Lines[3]); }
                                 }
                    }
```